# Missing or Insufficient Permissions: Firestore security rules angularfire2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I am trying to implement security rules to retrieve documents matching the current user id.  According to the [Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query?authuser=0) I should have a restrictive rule for a query with `where` clause, which is what I have done.

I would like the security rules to be more restrictive and can't seem to figure out why the below rule is not matching.

```
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6,
"firebase" : "4.10.1",
"@firebase/firestore": "0.3.4",
```

​**message: "Missing or insufficient permissions**

**Here are my security rules ( working and non-working comments)**
Security Rules

```
match /passwords/{password} {

    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    function userMatches() {
        return resource.data.user_id == request.auth.id;
    }

    allow write: if isSignedIn();
    allow read: if isSignedIn(); // works
    allow read: if userMatches(); //doesn't work 
}
```

**Client Side Code**

```
getPasswords(): Observable<IPasswordItem[]> {
        const whereClause = ref => ref.where('user_id', '==', this.authService.getCurrentUserId());
        return this.afs.collection<IPasswordItem>('passwords', whereClause).valueChanges();
}
```